# Possible XSS detected with isset on echo

Tags: php

I'm currently cleaning up my code with PHPCS Security Audit, on one of the lines it says "Easy XSS detected because of direct user input with $_POST on echo" I've spent the last 4 hours on Google and the PHP manual trying to figure this out without any solution, if anyone could help me I'd much appreciate it, thank you.

My code is:

```
<?php echo isset($_POST['email']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES) : "";  ?>
```

Comment: Your code seems fine to me, although personally I'd go with `echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'] ?? "", ENT_QUOTES);` instead.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - Thank you very much, your solution cleared the error, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: it would be safer to use `filter_input`instead of `$_POST` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) in this case `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`..

Comment: @spielerds - Thank you very much, I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't fix this issue until I stored $_POST['email'] in a sanitised variable and then used that in if statements and for echoing.